# Java program that will ask the height and width of a rectangle and display the rectangle using "*" and "+"

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my program and it is quite frustrating! Ive been trying to solve this but I cant pls I need help.All I can do is this

```
import java.util.*;       

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter height: ");
        int h = s.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter width: ");
        int w = s.nextInt();

        for (int i=1; i<=h; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=w; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of my program is:

```
Enter height: 4
Enter width: 4


****
****
****
****
```

And the desired output should be:

```
Enter height: 4
Enter with: 4

++++
****
++++
****
```

Another thing is to write program that is the same but different output Which will be:

```
Enter height: 3
Enter width: 10

+*+*+*+*+*
+*+*+*+*+*
+*+*+*+*+*
```

Thanks in advance for those who will help.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW6SY.jpg)

Comment: You have made your code a lot harder to read, and it *still* isn't valid Java. If you have code that you are running, at least copy and paste that, but try to get the indentation right too, and put one statement per line.

Comment: Your code does not even compile (e.g. `importjava` and `Static`). Fix your code first, then think of the problem and how you could solve it, before you ask a specific question. StackOverflow is no code (or homework assignment) writing service.

Comment: Her algorithm for when to choose `*` over `+` is not obvious and also isn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: use s.close() on the last line

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes but I am just new in programming and I want to learn and understand java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first solution, 
Put this code inside inner loop

```
if(i%2==1)
    System.out.print("+");
else 
    System.out.print("*");
```

For second solution:
Use above code just replace 'if(i%2==1)' with 'if(j%2==1)'

Answer (score 0):

you can check on even / uneven row, using `i % 2 == 0`

Comment: my answer does not provide a full answer, but gives a reasonable direction towards one. but point taken